# Unable to parse query string error Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working in this spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9bpjrdMsxJf-FkA5ns6hk8_nxc0UWf66Z9N2NHTNuw/edit?usp=sharing

and despite the fact that my formulas work for a majority of cells in Columns E,F, and N on **sheet1**,  the following error message continues to pop up for the remaining cells:

> "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   NO_COLUMN: Col2"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is typical. There are often questions from people who have formulas like this:

```
= QUERY (IMPORTRANGE(...), "select ...")
```

or this:

```
= QUERY (IMPORTHTML(...), "select ...")
```

And they got error from `query` like this:

> NO_COLUMN: ColN

But the problem is not in `query`, but in data. To test it, try counting `import` formula separately, in empty cell use this:

```
=IMPORTHTML(...)
```

And then you'll see that it won't give desired output.

---

For your particular case, I guess there's too much `importhtml` in one file, and it can't load it all at once. You use importhtml several times, and query it each time, and it overloads the file. You may use separate worksheet for `importhtml` only and see if it loads correctly, then query this worksheet in the final report.